# ENOENT: no such file or directory, open uploads

Tags: node.js, mongodb, server, multer, netlify

I want to upload pictures to my nodejs app which has been hosted on netlify,
it work on the local environment but after hosting on netlify it seems it can't locate the **uploads** folder to put the file there...

Upload code

```
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");

let storage = multer.diskStorage({
 destination: (req, file, cb) => {
   cb(null, "./uploads");
 },
 filename: (req, file, cb) => {
   let pathname = path.extname(file.originalname);
   cb(null, Date.now() + pathname);
 },
});

let upload = multer({
 storage: storage,
 fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
   if (file.mimetype === "image/png" || file.mimetype === "image/jpg") {
     console.log("ok");
     cb(null, true);
   } else {
     console.log("Jpg and png only");
     cb(null, false);
   }
 },
 limits: { fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 2 },
});


module.exports = upload
```

route

```
productRouter
  .route("/")
  .post(upload.single("image"), addProduct);
```

Comment: Well of course, netlify doesn't have `upload` folder. So how can you save to something that doesn't exist?!? That folder exists only in your local environment

Comment: @Shivam But I have **uploads** folder in my github repo...

Comment: @Shivam is there any other alternative?

Comment: Well you would have to store your files in third party storage services like - AWS S3 or Google Cloud Storage because If I remember correctly, Netlify doesn't offer cloud storage.